# Output precision with gvar

Tags: python, gvar

Using `gvar` in `python` it is possible to pretty print a number with its uncertainty between parenthesis, see [documentation](https://gvar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).
For example:

```
import gvar
a = gvar.gvar(1.231,0.382)
print(a)
```

gives output:

```
1.23(38)
```

Is it possible to control the number of digits for the error bar?

For example, I would like to have the above numbers with, say, 1 digit of precision, as

```
1.2(4)
```

or with 3 digits as

```
1.231(382)
```

**Addition**: With number of digits I intend the number of significant digits of the error bar. So for example, given

```
a = gvar.gvar(1.231,0.0382)
```

with 1 digit I would have

```
1.23(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

For exporting `gvar` variable to string (for example to printing) you can use [gvar.fmt](https://gvar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gvar.html#gvar.fmt) method:

```
import gvar
a = gvar.gvar(1.231,0.382)
print(a.fmt(1)) # 1.2(4)
print(a.fmt(2)) # 1.23(38)
print(a.fmt(3)) # 1.231(382)
```

Comment: Perhaps the question was not clear: see edit. I would like to fix the number of digits between the parenthesis. With ```gvar.fmt``` I have to set the the decimals of the number itself.